# I'd like to know why the result of the average of array always wrong

Tags: c, arrays

(I want to write a code to calculate the sum and average of the elements of an array)
I wanted to find out the reason for the wrong average result where the average might be float so I made the cast to convert the result to float using `(float)sum)/size`.

**NOTE**: I know if I definite variable average this problem will be solved

```c
float average = (float)sum/arr_size;
printf("The average of the array elements is: %f\n", average);
```

But I need analysis of my wrong output of average

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 5
int main(void)
{ 
  int i,sum=0;
  int arr[size];
  printf("please enter array elements: \n");
  // for loop to scant element elemnt of array
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
      scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  }
  // sum of array
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
      sum+=arr[i];
  }
  // print sum after fishing
  printf("the summation is : %d \n",sum);

  // average of array
  printf("The average of array : %d",(((float)sum)/size));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` should be `%f`.

Comment: did you ignore the compiler warning that your output format is incorrect - `%d` should be `%f`

Comment: "why the result of the average of array always wrong" --> Because code was not compiled with a good compiler with warnings all enabled.  Example: "warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cast `((float)sum))` but still use `%d` in your `printf`.  Use `%f` and add a newline.

```
printf("The average of array : %f\n", (((float)sum)/size));
```

Comment: The `float` value is automatically converted to `double` by the rules for calling variable-argument functions like `printf()`.  The code might as well cast to `double`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is this happen every time we use `printf()` to print a `float`?

Comment: Yes.  C11 [§6.5.2.2 Function calls §6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6): _If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions._.  This defines 'default argument promotions'. The paragraph also says (in material just after the quote) that you must have a prototype for `printf()` in scope when you call it to avoid undefined behaviour […continued…]

Comment: […continuation…] [§6.5.2.2 ¶7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p7): _If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments._